# how to pass parameters to popover content function of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add conditions as to what type of text should be shown in popovers.
So I wrote the function:

```
var initErrorPopOverEvent = function(hasRequiredError,option){
         if(hasRequiredError !== undefined && hasRequiredError === true){
             $(".icon-warning-lg").popover({
                 html:true,
                 placement:'top',
                'trigger': 'hover ',
                 content:function(){
                     return $("#required-field-error").text();
                 }
             });
         }
         if(option !== undefined){
             if(option === "option1"||option === "option2"){
                 $("#opt1-warning").popover({
                     html:true,
                     placement:'top',
                    'trigger': 'hover ',
                     content:function(){
                         return $("#opt1-error").text();
                     }
                 });
             }
             if(option === "option3" || option === "option2"){
                 $("#opt2-warning").popover({
                     html:true,
                     placement:'top',
                    'trigger': 'hover ',
                     content:function(){
                         return $("#opt2-error").text();
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     }
```

But I want all these conditions to go inside the function which displays popover content.
something like:

```
content:function(hasRequiredError,option){//render text according to condition
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it a map in Javascript. {key:value}

Try this:

```
var hasRequiredError = ...;
var option = ...;
var options = {'content':initErrorPopOverEvent(hasRequiredError,option)};

$('#myElement').popover( options );
```